# What is equivalent for logf from C in JAVA?

Tags: java, math, logarithm

What is equivalent for logf from C in JAVA?
Using `math.h` I have:

```
logf (extern float logf _PARAMS((float));)
```

I want use float in JAVA.

Thank you for your advice and help!

Comment: Would be great if you explain what `logf` does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`java.lang.Math.log(double a)`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_log.htm)

Given it does not use floats, but instead doubles. There is not native java support for logs on a float level.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`Math.log(double e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log-double-) which accepts and returns type `double`:

```
float log = (float) Math.log(1.0f);
```

By casting the result to `float` you obviously lose precision so you could just keep it as double:

```
double log = Math.log(1.0f);
```